# How long can a cellphone battery(pictured) power a LED light that produces light equivalent to traditional 60W bulb(800 lumens)?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-engineering, batteries

Assuming Energy Star rated LEDs which produces 100 lumens/watts. Battery rated as 9.88Wh.

Power consumption by LED = 800 lumens/100lumens/watt = 8 Watts

Does it mean that it will power circuit for 9.88/8 = 1.235 Hours? Or I have to look for 3.8V & do calculations around that?

[image: Example Battery]

Comment: Yes, you should refer to the standard voltage that the led needs to produce the light with 8W, i.e. the 3.6eV battery applied on the LED, the LED may not produce 8W illumination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is basically correct. If a battery is rated at 9.88WHrs it will produce a power of 1 Watt for 9.88 hours, or 8 Watts for 1.235 hours.

However the power rating depends on what current the battery is producing. There will be an optimal current that gives the highest capacity, and the battery power rating is calculated for this optimum current. If the current you are drawing is higher or lower than the optimum the energy you'll get from the battery will be slightly lower.

Note also that you may need some messing around with voltages. The light rating of the LEDs assumes the LEDs are being powered at their optimum voltage, and there's no reason to suppose this is exactly the 3.8V that the battery provides.